# Consuming var group value in place of yaml template parameter

Tags: environment-variables, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a `yml` file which calls a templated stage:

```
- template: pipeline-templates/iac/deploy-template.yml
  parameters:
    envName: dev
    varGroup: dev-variables-group-library
```

In the template I have made use of the template parameter:

```
parameters:
    envName: ''
    varGroup: ''

stages:
- stage: Deploy_for_${{ parameters.envName }}
```

I want to use the `envName` variable from the variable group, instead of the template parameters. I have tried template code like this:

```
parameters:
    envName: ''
    varGroup: ''

stages:
- stage: Deploy_for_$( envName )
```

When I do this, the pipeline throws an unrelated error, for example stating that the stage name cannot be duplicate. This is clearly because the variable `envName` is not being read.

There are other places in my template where the pipeline variable is read and used successfully, so what am I doing wrong in this particular part of the template script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if wanted to use a variable group need to define the group to be read in:

```
- group: ${{parameters.varGroup}}
```

After doing this should be able to reference by `$(envName)` or if compile time is alright can also specify `${{ varaibles.envName }}`

[Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azuredevops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch&WT.mc_id=AZ-MVP-5004321#runtime-expression-syntax)

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't noticed that I was missing that declaration. D'oh!